# Setting PHP environment variable on GAE dev mode (dev_appserver.py)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, environment-variables

I have Zend Framework project running on Google App Engine. Everything works great, with the exception of one thing:

**I can't set an environment variable to tell Zend that I'm in development mode**

Any ideas?

(I'm using PHP 5.4 in Ubuntu)

---

**What I've tried**

(Obviously I don't want to set the variable through app.yaml... I can't set it through .htaccess because it's not used. I would rather not have to add any conditions in my code to possibly set the variable that way, either)

I'm using PHPStorm (IDE), which has a nice plugin for GAE. It even has an option in the project configurations for environment variables - except that it doesn't work. I'm setting the variable in PHPStorm (Edit Configurations > Google App Engine for PHP > Command Line > Environment Variables), but if I do a

```
getenv()
```

from code, it returns

```
boolean false
```

---

**Why**

My goal in all this is to dynamically load the development configurations for my project, particuarly so I can use MySQL locally, instead of connecting up to CloudSQL while developing and testing the apps.

Comment: What is wrong with setting it in app.yaml ?  Secondly you could look at the env variable SERVER_SOFTWARE  which will have the value ""Development/X.Y" where "X.Y" is the version of the runtime."

Comment: I am missing something in your requirements, why isn't `-mysql_host MYSQL_HOST
                        host name of a running MySQL server used for simulated
                        Google Cloud SQL storage (default: localhost)`
  command line option enough for you to use a local dev mysql server ?

Comment: If I set it in app.yaml, then I'd have to change the file every time I deploy. Otherwise, my production env would be configured to use the dev database settings. This is pretty common in Zend Framework projects, where one normally set this env var in the virtual host file. The whole point being that the code base never has to change, but it behaves differently depending on the environment it's running in.

Comment: So why is the command line option I mentioned not appropriate ?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't seem to work with the command line options.  If it didn't work on a widespread scale the no one could do appengine cloud SQL dev,

Comment: Try the command line running the SDK outside of your IDE in case that's the problem

Comment: Ah, looking back at your first answer, I guess I can indeed just check for the substring "development" in the SERVER_SOFTWARE variable, then adjust the config accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I don't like that, because you now have to put code in place that checks dev vs prod, which is worse than automating changes to app.yaml IMO :-). The command line options for the dev server are ultimatleyh the best solution and they should work.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll survive with this solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I'm going with, based on the comments by @tim-hoffman is the following little bit of logic on my /public/index.php file, placed before the APPLICATION_ENV constant is defined:

```
$env = getenv("SERVER_SOFTWARE");
if ($env !== false) {
   if ((bool)preg_match("/development/", strtolower($env))) {
      define("APPLICATION_ENV", "development");
   }
}
```

In development mode, SERVER_SOFTWARE will return the string "Development/X.X" (version number), and in production, it'll be "Google App Engine/X.Y.Z"

Comment: yeh this is probably the best way